# Codename One Pubnub alternatives CN1lib

Tags: real-time, codenameone, pubnub, pusher, ably-realtime

I am looking for Pubnub alternatives in Codename One for real time communication. Are there available cn1libs for [Pusher](https://pusher.com) for example? If there is not one, is it possible to write a cn1lib using the existing Android and iOS libraries for Pusher?

Comment: Just wondering why you prefer an alternative to PubNub (in the spirit of constructive feedback that we can use to improve).

Comment: It is too expensive.

Comment: PubNub now offer transaction pricing.

Answer (score 2):

I really like pubnub and it has a pretty generous free tier but these sort of discussions are discouraged on stackoverflow so I'll answer the question of "Is it possible to write a cn1lib using the existing Android/iOS libraries of an SDK?"

Yes. We even have a tutorial on doing this in the developer guide [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html). Steve also made some videos covering the subject [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html).

Comment: Shai, are there any plans to support any other library than pubnub now that the pubnub SDK would not be updated? I would suggest looking also into Fanout.io

Comment: We don't have any such plans at this time. If I'd invest time in it I'd work on websockets rather than one of those tools. Notice you can wrap any native library with a Codename One cn1lib which is a pretty easy process for these types of libraries as they contain no UI.

Answer (score 1):

We have not explicitly tried our [Ably realtime client libraries](https://www.ably.io/download) with Codename One, however they are built with portable Java and should therefore work.  We are a [very appealing alternative to PubNub and Pusher](https://www.ably.io/compare).

Matt, co-founder of [Ably: simply better realtime](https://www.ably.io)

Comment: Ably looks very interesting, especially the flexible pricing :) But in Codename One, jars are not guaranteed to work, since they may use some not supported Java features. I will try it as soon as possible though